# Regular expression in javascript for at least one character including special character

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to validate a text box, to have any character, but not empty.

This is my current code

```
condition = '\\d{9}';
condition = new RegExp(condition);
    if (condition.test(element.val())) {
             //some code
        }
```

But, i want it to **allow all characters, but not empty,** 
I have already tried .{50}, /.*/s and [\s\S]*  , But none seem to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex matches only strings with 9 digits. For at least a single character, use `.*[^\\s].*` which ensures at least one non-space character.

Comment: yep, it was just for an example sake, i needed something to check for not empty.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you use jQuery. Try to pass value to [`$.trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) to cut all non-space characters:

```
if ($.trim(element.val()).length > 0) {
    // ...
}
```

In case if you don't use jQuery, there is [`String.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) method available. Check the compatibility information at [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim#Compatibility).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, i am aware of that , but i HAVE to use a regex as asked in the question. Got it though... :) [^\\s]

Comment: @Archer At ["Compatibility"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim#Compatibility) section you will find how to use regex for trimming.

Answer (score 1):

If it can be any character, but not empty, you could just test the length of the input's current value. E.g.

```
if (element.val().length > 0) {
    //some code
}
```

If you must use a regex then the following will work:

```
condition = /.+/;
```

Comment: Yes, i know this, but i WANT to give a regex to 'condition' variable. and then test it, as in the question.

Comment: Notice that if `element` is a textarea, and it contains multiple lines, this regexp will fails – when I read the title of the question, I interpreted "special characters" for this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question:

```
condition = '^[\\s\\S]+$';
condition = new RegExp(condition);

if (condition.test(element.val())) {
    //some code
}
```

It will pass for any string that as at least one character, and fails for empty string. Notice that also whitespace are considered, so if `element.val()` is `"  "` it will returns `true`. If you want to returns `false` in this case too, you have just to remove `\\s` from the string above.